# Faraday::TimeoutError","Operation timed out after some seconds.." Searchkick while reindexing with associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to reindex my searchkick model which looks like this

```
class Collectible < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick suggest: ["name"], text_start: [:name], wordnet: true
   has_many   :category_collectibles, dependent: :delete_all
   has_many   :categories , :through=> :category_collectibles
   has_many   :georesults, dependent: :delete_all

   scope :search_import, -> { includes(:categories) }

  def search_data
     attributes.merge(
      states: georesults.map(&:state),
      categories: categories.map(&:name)
     )
   end
```

here is my category model

```
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many   :category_collectibles, dependent: :delete_all
     has_many   :collectibles , :through=> :category_collectibles
  end
```

Category_collectible model

```
 class CategoryCollectible < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collectible ,inverse_of: false
  belongs_to :category
 end
```

georesults model

```
class Georesult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collectible
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collectible
end
```

I have about 120k records in collectible georesult table and about  300k record in category_collectibles and 500 records in categories, while reindexing I checked my systems memory usage and was normal but not sure why I am getting timeout error

```
Collectible Import (11372.8ms)  {"count":1000,"exception":["Faraday::TimeoutError","Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"]}
```

Comment: 'Normal' memory usage can appear even if various buffers are not set big enough, so a process starts to use (very slow) swap memory on disk. Have you checked to see if this is the case? Also 10 seconds seems like quite a small timeout. Have you tried raising it?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you remove the `text_start` and `wordnet` options?  Both options increase the index size dramatically, so there's a good chance Elasticsearch needs more resources.

Comment: Yes I tried with all the available options and found that the latest version of searchkick was having some issues related to timeouts so I reverted it back to serachkick 0.8.0 removed the scope and it worked